# How to link an email account to Facebook in Spring Social?

Tags: facebook, spring-mvc, facebook-graph-api, twitter, spring-social

I have been some time trying to figure out how to solve this. Let me explain in detail to you.

I'm developing a web app in Spring MVC and Spring Social. By now, users can sigin and signup with Facebook, Twitter and with user/password. Even those users signedin with Facebook/Twitter are able to share.

Now, the webapp owner wants that any user signedup with user/password, he/she can  link his/her active account with his/her Facebook profile. This way, those users can post on his/her Facebook wall.

Any of you have an idea about how to accomplish this?

By now, I have tried to get FB token through Graph API http link, but URL shows FB secret property.

Any ideas?

Comment: when you say link email..do u mean they wouldn't have to login to fb?So the user would login to the webapp with their username / password. They can then post to FB (without logging in to FB?)?

Comment: I meant that users have an option to signin with a personal username/password (not linked to FB). And once logged in they have the option to link their account to FB, so next time they signin must do it with FB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am understanding this correctly a very similar scenario is covered in the spring social sample project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples

Once a user is logged into your webapp

1. They would need to connect to Facebook via spring social (Spring social connect controller would handle this).
2. They would need to authorize your app to access their facebook.
3. (spring social does this), After the authentication process you obtain a key that you can keep for the next session.
4. Once they are logged in, you have an instance of Facebook Connection(spring-social-facebook creates this), and you can use it to post to their wall

   ```
   connection.updateStatus("I've connected with the Spring Social Showcase!");
   ```

   There are also other operations you can perform against the Facebook API.

Hope this helps answer your question.

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Great! Thank you Paul! I will review spring-social-samples, and I will follow the steps you propose.

Comment: hi Omar, if this helped, it would be really great for me, if you mark this answer correct and vote this. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: By now, I have the spring-social-showcase-sec running... Spring sent me "Error resolving template signin..." everytime I tryied to run the project. I found a solution: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/issues/32.

Comment: oh yeah....i just remembered that jira..so..does this help resolve your requirement? I just saw i had commented on that jira too.

Comment: I tried to run spring-social-samples and got "Error resolving template signin..." error again!. I have been reading http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/, and still doesn't get to solve what I need. When I call "oauthOperations.exchangeForAccess" method a I got "bad request" error... So, I kind of stuck!

Comment: did u try setting  templateResolver.setPrefix("/views/") in WebMvcConfig.java

Comment: For some reason, I think compiler was not working with the latest changes, because right now it's working the spring-social-samples project. Config file has the prefix like this: "templateResolver.setPrefix("views/");"

Comment: You know, I don't understand what Spring does after user authorize to connect Facebook. How do I obtain the FB key?

Comment: use the facebooktemplate object and you can access the key from that..did u see that object?

Comment: I have this method: `FacebookConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new FacebookConnectionFactory(social.getFacebookKey(), social.getFacebookSecret());
        OAuth2Operations oauthOps = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();
     AccessGrant accessGrant = oauthOps.exchangeForAccess(code, "http://localhost:8080/hyperion/settings/account-linked", null);
     Connection<Facebook> connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);`. All I got it's an error.

Comment: I tryied this other code: `OAuth2Template oauth = new OAuth2Template(social.getFacebookKey(), social.getFacebookSecret(), "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth", "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token");
     AccessGrant accessGrant = oauth.authenticateClient();
     FacebookTemplate facebook = new FacebookTemplate(accessGrant.getAccessToken());`. And again, I got the same error!

Comment: Omar to connect to facebook - try this -   Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate("Your facebook app key"); This will give you the facebookObject connectd. You can see this in the spring social samples project.

Comment: You know, I think somethink it's wrong with this app. I tested the next code `Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(social.getFacebookKey());
        log.debug("Facebook {}", facebook);        
        try{
        log.debug("Facebook profile {}",facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile());
        }catch(InvalidAuthorizationException ex){
         return "redirect:/auth/facebook";
        }
          return "redirect:/profile";` Once the code it's executed, I got redirected to Facebook login page. After write my FB credentials, I got redirected to */signin#_=_*, with an error message.

Comment: The error message is `Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.c
ore.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: Unknown connected account id`

Comment: omar..Check out this http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/  Maybe it will help. Spring social samples projects work fine for me locally.

Comment: As long as I understand, the web app I working on has SocialAuthenticationFilter configured, so it responds to auth/facebook (not connect/facebook). Today, I have been doing some tests, and I think this filter is catching any calll to facebook. So, everytime I tried to connect a user with his facebook account, I got redirected to 'register' a new user screen. @PaulJohn, do you really think it is possible to have both worlds tide together? Because in spring-sample, a user can connect to facebook, but it never convert his username/email account in a FB oauth account. I think it is not possible!